# Error writng to csv, not allowing me to write Python3 and csvwriter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

Having a problem with this code:

```
    i = range(0, 51)

    page_number = 1
    with open('hltb data/HLTB.csv','w') as f: 
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow(['Game Name:', 'Game Length:', 'Game Developer:', "Game Publisher:", 'Game Genre:', 'Game Console:', 'URL:']) 
 for element in i:
        url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=' + format(page_number)

        response = get(url)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        page_number += 1

        try:
            game_name = html_soup.select('div.profile_header')[0].text
        except:
            game_name = "Game Name not found"

        try:     
            game_length = html_soup.select('div.game_times li div')[-1].string
        except:
            game_length = "Game length not found"

        try:
            game_developer = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nDeveloper:\n')[0].next_sibling
        except:
            game_developer = "Game developer not found"

        try:
            game_publisher = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nPublisher:\n')[0].next_sibling
        except:
            game_publisher = "Game Publisher not found"

        try:
            game_console = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nPlayable On:\n')[0].next_sibling
        except:
            game_console = "Game Playable on not found"

        try:
            game_genres = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nGenres:\n')[0].next_sibling
        except:
            game_genres = "Game Genres found"

        print(url)
        print(game_name)
        print(game_length)
        print(game_developer)
        print(game_publisher)
        print(game_genres)
        print(game_console)

        row = [game_name, game_length, game_developer, game_publisher, game_genres, game_console, url]
        thewriter.writerow(row)
```

I'm getting this error when I run the code:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>        46 
>        47        row = [game_name, game_length, game_developer, game_publisher, game_genres, game_console, url]
>   ---> 48        thewriter.writerow(row)
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I had it working before.

How to do data scraping and transferring the info into a spreadsheet so I can manipulate the data?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are performing you `for` loop outside of your `with open()` on the open file. move the `for` loop so it is contained in `with open()`:

```
[...]
with open('hltb data/HLTB.csv','w') as f: 
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['Game Name:', 'Game Length:', 'Game Developer:', "Game Publisher:", 'Game Genre:', 'Game Console:', 'URL:']) 
    for element in i:
        url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=' + format(page_number)
        [...]
```

edit: i meant `with open()`, not while. fixed my post and am making some coffee...

Comment: @littlejiver it's much nicer when it's something small than something big lol. if the answer worked for you, make sure to mark it answered so other people can find it helpful for them too.

Comment: even a better design is to make your data, and dump later to file. this way you avoid part of the mess